# EmulateIE7 mode set in IIS7/web.config does not show page in proper mode in IE11

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-11, x-ua-compatible, compatibility-mode

I have a web site and IE8, IE9, and IE10 always worked great using IE=EmulateIE7 mode in HTTP header response from IIS/7, but this mode does not seem to render properly in IE11.

The page does not render or behave properly in IE11, although it works fine in EmulateIE7 mode in IE8 through IE10.
If I open F12 tools on IE11, I see the document mode is "7."

The only way to make IE11 working properly is adding manualy the domain to compatibility view mode, then it works great; but we cannot ask all users to manually activate compatibility view for our domains.

How is possible to force IE11 to render as IE7 without adding the domain to the list of compatibility web sites ?

Many thanks to any help !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working on this the last few days and there's some bad news, it works, but in order to make it work, the user must add the URL/Domain of your site to the "Compatibility View Settings" of IE 11.

In other words, you can't force the browser to render in compatibility mode without the explicit acceptance of the user.

You will find how to configure it here:

www.windows8core.com/how-to-view-and-configure-compatibility-settings-in-internet-explorer-11-of-windows-8-1/

Comment: Many thaks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get this to work if I add the X-UA-Compatible header in IIS itself. Not sure why it doesn't work when added to web.config