# upper IE 8 does not IE Embedded WinForm

Tags: winforms, internet-explorer

I know that It doensn't work.
But It's so late to develop another project.

I just want to know how to excute it on Windows 8 and IE 11

whether direct way or indirect way. It's OK.

I'm almost crazy 'cause of this problem.

for a long time I coudn't find any information on searching.

Microsoft said ..

> IEHost.dll is the runtime host that provides the ability to host
>   Windows Forms controls and run executables in IE. IEHost is a .Net 1.1
>   technology that provided a better model than ActiveX to host controls
>   within the browser since they were lightweight and the controls
>   operated under the .NET security model, where they operated inside a
>   sandbox.
>
> For Dev10, the proposal is to remove IEHost.dll for the following
>   reasons
>
> 1. IEHost/HREF-EXEs are surface area exposed to the Internet. This poses a high security risk (we already have bugs filed related to
>      this), and most customers (by far) who install the Framework are
>      getting very little value for this security risk. If IEHost and IEExec
>      is left as-is, a new model needs to be designed where either (a) using
>      this technology is safe and is always on, or (b) is as secure as today
>      and can be configured to be turned off. The cost of doing this is very
>      high.
> 2. Customers who want IEHost/HREF-EXE-sytle controls or apps have numerous other technologies they can use, like ClickOnce, XBAP,
>      Silverlight.
> 3. Customers who want the exact same functionality as 3.5 SP1 for this feature can continue to use 3.5 SP1. This change, of removing
>      IEHost takes effect only in .Net Framework 4.0.
> 4. The opportunity cost and risk of continuing to support this feature for the CLR team is high. Going forward, we will be able to
>      deliver more features and bug fixes that benefit more of our customers
>      if we can remove this from NetFx4.

Comment: **Solution:** get rid of that horrible abomination and either create a Web Application using Web technology (HTML / CSS / JS) or a Windows Desktop application using WPF, or a Windows 8+ "Metro" Style application using WinRT XAML. winforms is not only completely useless, it is also NOT a Web technology and running winforms stuff inside a Web application is the worst idea in the history of mankind. You cannot seriously expect that it is going to be supported in 2013+ in current OSes and current browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I know that your clients won't wait for a full re-write of your website, the show must continue right?, then for now follow these steps to make it work:

**Basic steps used in previous versions**

1. In IE add your site to TrustedSites.
2. Use Caspol.exe to grant full trust to your site.

**New steps to use with .Net Framework 4 and IE 11**

3. [Re-enable IE host support for IE (Review this post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334664/loading-net-usercontrols-in-ie-with-net-4-0/3342543#3342543)
4. [Optional: If your site needs to run in compatibility mode add it to "Compatibility View Settings" (Review this post).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977538/emulateie7-mode-set-in-iis7-web-config-does-not-show-page-in-proper-mode-in-ie11/19992160#19992160)

**Something important to note:**
This behavior will be the same in any version of Window/IE if you have .Net Framework 4+ installed. i.e. If you have your site running in IE 8/9 and then you install .Net Framework 4 your embedded winforms won't be loaded, you will need to follow the new steps below.

However I completely agree with @HighCore, you must get rid of it, it is a time bomb.